# Не работает выбор контролов с DockStyle.Top

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

У меня есть панель с контролами, у некоторых Dock = DockStyle.Top, у некоторых Bottom.
Через

```cs
Form1.pageWithMessages.Controls.OfType<UserControl4> ().Select (x => x.Dock == DockStyle.Top).Count ();
```

Пытаюсь подсчитать количество контролов с DockStyle.Top, но почему-то Select возвращает все контролы, даже те, которые не надо. В чём может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо за ответ!

P.S. Я проверял, в панеле есть контролы с DockStyle.Bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не правильно пользуетесь LINQ, `Select()` нужен тогда, когда надо изменить представление элементов. Он вычисляет выражение для каждого элемента. Результатом выполнения вашего запроса, если убрать `Count()`

```
Form1.pageWithMessages
   .Controls
   .OfType<UserControl4>()
   .Select(x => x.Dock == DockStyle.Top);
```

будет набор элементов типа `DockStyle` со значением `DockStyle.Top`, а количество их будет совпадать с количеством всех контролов типа `UserControl4`.

Чтобы отфильтровать элементы используется другой метод - `Where()`. Но так как вам нужно лишь количество элементов, правильный вариант перенести условие в `Count()` -- он также поддерживает условия(предикаты) как аргумент.

```
Form1.pageWithMessages
   .Controls
   .OfType<UserControl4>()
   .Count(x => x.Dock == DockStyle.Top);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло Count(x => x.Dock == DockStyle.Top). Пытался до этого также, но из-за Select, выдавало ошибку. А про Where чего-то забыл.